# Cannot borrow member of own struct as mutable when using generics

Tags: rust

I have what I would consider to be the fairly trivial code:

```
pub struct BestType<'a, T: 'a + Read + Write> {
    socket: &'a T,
}

impl<'a, T: Read + Write> BestType<'a, T> {
    pub fn read(&mut self, mut container: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        let mut socket = self.socket;
        socket.read(&mut container)
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to compile it, I get the following error:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*socket` as mutable
   --> src\lib.rs:780:9
    |
780 |         socket.read(&mut container)
    |         ^^^^^^
```

What's going on? If I have the following code instead:

```
pub struct BestType<'a> {
    socket: &'a TcpStream,
}

impl<'a> BestType<'a> {
    pub fn read(&mut self, mut container: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        let mut socket = self.socket;
        socket.read(&mut container)
    }
}
```

That compiles just fine.

I can't see what's causing the difference - all I'm trying to do is, instead of hard-coding a `TcpStream`, have the caller pass me a type that implements both `Read` and `Write` (like `TcpStream`!).

```
rustc 1.15.0 (10893a9a3 2017-01-19)
rustc 1.15.1 (021bd294c 2017-02-08)
cargo 0.16.0-nightly (6e0c18c 2017-01-27)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your original code:

```
pub struct BestType<'a, T: 'a + Read + Write> {
    socket: &'a T,
}

impl<'a, T: Read + Write> BestType<'a, T> {
    pub fn read(&mut self, mut container: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        let mut socket = self.socket;
        socket.read(&mut container)
    }
}
```

The [Read trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html)'s `read` method takes `&mut self`.  This makes sense (even though "read" doesn't sound like it mutates), since you may be moving a read pointer for example.

When you call `socket.read()`, the type has to be `T` (which is the only type implementing `Read`), but you've only got an immutable reference to it.

In your second version, instead of having an `&T` where `T: Read`, you have an explicit `&TcpStream`.  The key difference is that `Read` happens to be implemented not only for `TcpStream` itself, but *also for `&TcpStream`*.  So as well as being able to `read` from `&mut TcpStream`, you can also read from `&mut &TcpStream`.  This is why this version compiles with `let mut socket = self.socket`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, changing it to

```
pub struct BestType<'a, T: 'a + Read + Write> {
    socket: &'a mut T,
}

impl<'a, T: Read + Write> BestType<'a, T> {
    pub fn read(&mut self, mut container: &mut [u8]) -> std::io::Result<usize> {
        let mut socket = self.socket;
        socket.read(&mut container)
    }
}
```

Was literally all it took. That said, I don't understand why this is required, or why it's different when using generics vs not...

Plus, in my actual code, I have to use `let ref mut`, not `let mut`, which I don't fully understand either, but at least it all compiles! I would love to accept an answer that provides a proper explanation of what's going on.